# Three dots (...) when I print a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I created a list of arrays with lots of data, for example:

```
[[233,443423,2554,4534,453245,254554,......], [343,6564,453,356,45645,........],....]
```

(approximately 1 million lists each containing 13 elements)

The problem is, when I try to print this list of lists it prints only 6 lists and only 6 elements from each list, with three dots in between the lists and between the elements.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are these `numpy` arrays? Or standard Python lists?

Comment: these are numpy arrays

Comment: Use `str.join()` explicitly if you don't mind the memory use. Otherwise it's probably better to just print them piece-by-piece yourself. Alternately, try `pprint`, maybe that doesn't attempt to buffer the output in memory first. (Maybe.)

Comment: @millimoose: No, this is a NumPy feature, see the proposed dupe.

Comment: thank you Martijn Pieters, it now works fine!